# Are there any publications in English about the Saltukid dynasty of Erzurum?

Tags: byzantine-empire, turkey

I went to Turkey recently. I stayed in Istanbul and then I went to Erzurum. I noticed that the Historic structures in Erzurum were quite a bit older and different in architectural style (the Saltukids were much older than the Ottomans and not as influenced by Byzantine culture) than the ones found in Istanbul. I want to find or more about this dynasty but there aren't any English language texts about them. Does anyone actually know of any studies/books about them?

Comment: Well, request for sources is off topic on H:SE. But I won't vote to close.  I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about history. It is a request for study material references.

Answer (score 3):

Here
 Clifford Edmund Bosworth (2004). The New Islamic Dynasties: A Chronological and Genealogical Manual ISBN 0-7486-2137-7. Edinburgh University Press.

Next time, look at the bottom of the Wikipedia article.